# Local or global scope for objects instantiating PHP classes?

Tags: php, class, object, scope

When writing PHP code for a website, what is better:

```
<?php

  include ("myclass.php");
  $theClass = new MyClass();

  function x () {
    global $theClass;
    $theClass->theProperty="foo";
    $theClass->doStuff();
  }

  function y () {
    global $theClass;
    $theClass->theProperty="bar";
    $theClass->doStuff();form
  }

?>
```

or:

```
<?php

  include ("myclass.php");

  function x () {
    $theClass = new MyClass();
    $theClass->theProperty="foo";
    $theClass->doStuff ();
  }

  function y () {
    $theClass = new MyClass();
    $theClass->theProperty="bar";
    $theClass->doStuff ();
  }

?>
```

Which one of the above is preferable, and what are the advantages and disadvantages, if any, for each scope of **$theClass**?

Answer (score 2):

Better is [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) :^ )

```
  include ("myclass.php");

  function x (\MyClass $theClass) {
    $theClass->theProperty="foo";
    $theClass->doStuff ();
  }

  function y (\MyClass $theClass) {
    $theClass->theProperty="bar";
    $theClass->doStuff ();
  }
```

But it depends... :^ )

Comment: With regard to scope, why is DI better than the second snippet in the OP?

Comment: @FrankvanWensveen, for example. Today I had to inherit `DateInterval` to add new method. But I failed because dependence was not inverted in `$date_time1->diff($date_time2);`